# $routeUpdate not broadcast in angular karma unit test?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, unit-testing, jasmine

app.js

```
  'use strict';

angular
  .module('scrCliApp', [
    'ngRoute',
    'ui.bootstrap'
  ])
  .config(function ($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider
      .when('/search', {
        templateUrl: 'views/main.html',
        controller: 'MainCtrl',
        reloadOnSearch: false
      })
      .otherwise({
        redirectTo: '/search'
      });
  });
```

main.js controller

```
angular.module('scrCliApp')
  .controller('MainCtrl', function ($scope) {
    $scope.$on('$routeUpdate', function(/*scope, next, current*/) {
      console.log('i was called'); //never logs
    });
  });
```

main.js test

```
    'use strict';

describe('Controller: MainCtrl', function () {

  // load the controller's module
  beforeEach(module('scrCliApp'));

  var MainCtrl,
    scope,
    rootScope,
    location;

  // Initialize the controller and a mock scope
  beforeEach(inject(function ($controller, $rootScope, $location) {
    rootScope = $rootScope;
    location = $location;
    scope = $rootScope.$new();
    MainCtrl = $controller('MainCtrl', {
      $scope: scope
    });
  }));

  it('do call', function () {
    location.search('q', 'b');
    scope.$apply();
  });
});
```

when running the test, "i was called" never logs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you should just broadcast the event yourself, and then test what to do with it :

```
it('do call', function () {

    scope.$emit('$routeUpdate', [1,2,3]);
    scope.$apply();

    expect....
});
```

Comment: thanks - using emit allowed me to remove my onRouteUpdateDoSomething method from the scope but still test it. Would be nice if things worked with just the location.search(x,y) & $apply() alone. Perhaps it's related to the reloadOnSearch: false